# Is there any way to create a new Gesture in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

SwiftUI is missing a Pan gesture (that is, both scale and offset), so I was trying to create one. However, it appears that the Gesture struct depends on private classes. For example:

```
public struct PinchGesture: Gesture {

    public struct PinchGestureValue: Equatable {
        var scale: CGFloat
        var anchor: UnitPoint
        var offset: CGSize
        var isPinching: Bool
    }
    
    public typealias Value = PinchGestureValue
    public typealias Body = Never
    
    var minimumScaleDelta: CGFloat
    var minimumDistance: CGFloat
    var coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace
    
    
    public init(minimumScaleDelta: CGFloat = 0.01, minimumDistance: CGFloat = 10, coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace = .local) {
        self.minimumScaleDelta = minimumScaleDelta
        self.minimumDistance = minimumDistance
        self.coordinateSpace = coordinateSpace
    }
    
    public static func _makeGesture(gesture: _GraphValue<PinchGesture>, inputs: _GestureInputs) -> _GestureOutputs<PinchGestureValue> {
      // Unable to complete
    }

}
```

This code cannot be completed, as the _GraphValue, _GestureInputs, and _GestureOutputs are private. Before I give in completely, I wanted to see if anyone has figured out a workaround.

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring this out at all? I'm also looking to create a new Gesture.

Comment: Nope - sorry. It appears that there's no way to do this currently. For this particular need I ended up creating a completely new ScrollView... ☹️

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SwiftUI provides a default implementation of `_makeGesture`:

```
extension Gesture where Self.Value == Self.Body.Value {
  public static func _makeGesture(gesture: SwiftUI._GraphValue<Self>, inputs: SwiftUI._GestureInputs) -> SwiftUI._GestureOutputs<Self.Body.Value>
}
```

The difficulty here is the constraint `Self.Value === Self.Body.Value`. That means your gesture's `body` can't be declared to return `some Gesture`, because `some Gesture` can't satisfy the constraint (even if its `Value` would match). So you have to give `body` a specific type. The easiest solution is to use the `AnyGesture` type eraser:

```
public struct PinchGesture: Gesture {

    ...

    public var body: AnyGesture<PinchGestureValue> {
        AnyGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
               .map { PinchGestureValue($0) }
        )
    }
}
```

In this code, Swift can infer `PinchGesture.Value = PinchGestureValue` and `PinchGesture.Body = AnyGesture<PinchGestureValue>`. Then it can prove `AnyGesture<PinchGestureValue>.Value == PinchGesture.Value`, so it can use the default implementation of `_makeGesture` provided by SwiftUI.

Unfortunately, I doubt you can use this to create your `PinchGesture`. Ultimately, your `body` is still restricted to combining SwiftUI's primitive gestures, which don't give you access the current `UIEvent` or `UITouch` objects.